# session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I defined my session variable, in my  `Global.asax` called `user` like this

```
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["idMap"] = "";
        Session["user"] = "";
    }
```

Also i have a `asp:Login` in where i set the value of the session variable in the event of `loggedIn`

```
    protected void lgnMapZone_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Session["user"] = lgnMapZone.UserName;
    }
```

My problem it's that when the users it's autenthicated, the void session_start it's called and erase my variable, how can i solved this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Session.Abandon()` destroys the session and the `Session_OnEnd` event is triggered. You should call this method when the user does a logout instead of log in.

You should probably call `Session.Clear()` which just removes all values (content) from the session Object while logging in.

This will resolve the issue that you have now.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the variable is set or not before you set it again in Session_Start.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

inside Session_Start:

```
if (Session["user"] != "")
    // Do something else
else
    // Set Session["user"] = "", etc
```